# Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement Implementation

Tags: c#, azure, azure-api-management

I am trying to implement Azure API Management APIs using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement` 4.0.4-preview.

No where I see documentation for implementation. I tried below code. but I am getting authentication error.

> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 'Authentication failed. The 'Authorization' header is provided in an invalid format.'

```
BasicAuthenticationCredentials basicAuthenticationCredentials = new BasicAuthenticationCredentials();
basicAuthenticationCredentials.UserName = "**********";
basicAuthenticationCredentials.Password = "*******";

var token = "Bearer **********"; // copied bear token from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/get by logging proper user name and password

 ApiManagementClient apiManagementClient = new ApiManagementClient(basicAuthenticationCredentials);
 apiManagementClient.SubscriptionId = "*************************************";           
 apiManagementClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", token);
 apiManagementClient.ApiManagementService.Get("resourcegroupname", "POCAPIManagementService"); // error happening from this line

 var user = apiManagementClient.User.Get("resourcegroupname", "POCAPIManagementService", "1");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After two weeks struggle we found way to Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement 
dll Implementation.

1) Create application inside azure ad 
2) Go to your APIM => Access control (IAM) Tab
3) Add the above created application (permission is required to do this in APIM)
4) Now you should be able to see Azure AD application in APIM Access control (IAM) Tab

This will provide delegated permission to your application which is created in Azure AD

We can use client credential flow to get delegated access token against Azure AD.
Use scope as https://management.azure.com

The sample code for implementing client credential flow for  Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement dll is given below.

```
public class myServiceCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials{
private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
    {
        var authenticationContext = new 
   AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}");
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxx", 
  clientSecret: "{clientSecret}");
        var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: 
        "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }
        AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

Thank you https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4727

Comment: helped me thanks. How do you invoke this? After you create the Rest client object somehow?

Comment: @Vetrivel, Is there anything we need to configure other than things specified by you.I'm getting 401 unauthorized issue. Do we need to configure Validate-JWT policy in APIM.

Comment: Don't forget to use the `AccessToken` in the `ApiManagementClient` like so: `client.SubscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.AuthenticationToken);`

Comment: See my comment on the Github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4727#issuecomment-789058005 for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

@Joseph, I had the same issue with unauthorized responses. Inspected the request made through the ApiManagementClient. Two things were wrong:

1. Wrong url
2. Missing authorization header.

Corrected this by doing:

```
var credentials = new MyCredentials();
var client = new ApiManagementClient(new Uri("https://management.azure.com/"), credentials);
client.SubscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
client.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + credentials.AuthenticationToken);
var result = await client.User.ListByServiceAsync("resource-group", "service");
```

MyCredentials looks the same as the myServiceCredentials class in the previous response and it inherits from ServiceClientCredentials. Had to make the AuthenticationToken prop public though.

Comment: I don't understand "Wrong url". Do you mean `new Uri("https://management.azure.com/")`? This is set in the package by default (version 6.0.0 preview)

Answer (score 0):

> copied bear token from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/user/get by logging proper user name and password

It seems that there is something wrong with the way you generate.

The authorization header should be a JSON Web Token that you obtain from Azure Active Directory, but directly from Azure Portal. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN#bk_common).

You can refer to this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/) for how to obtain a JWT from AAD and [protect an API by using OAuth 2.0 with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) and API Management.

Comment: My question is about how to implement Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement 4.0.4-preview dll. i really dont understand your answer. my intention is to programmatically do some activities against azure api management service. but you are talking about azure ad.

Comment: cacheId, what is it? where can I get it?

Comment: The cache key. Identifier of the Cache entity.