# Availability of SDK in C# for removing cache with Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there an SDK in C# available for removing cache with Azure APIM?

```
<cache-remove-value key="cache key value" caching-type="prefer-external | external | internal"  />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#RemoveCacheByKey

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CacheOperationsExtensions.Delete(ICacheOperations, String, String, String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.apimanagement.cacheoperationsextensions.delete?view=azure-dotnet) Method to remove cache with Azure APIM.

Also, the rest api to remove cache is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/cache/delete) with code to generate [access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108663/microsoft-azure-management-apimanagement-implementation/52112236#52112236).

Comment: The cacheId is the cache key which is identifier of the Cache entity.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no. There is an indirect way to reset cache by changing policy, this will force APIM to rotate cache keys and effectively invalidate cache. This will invalidate both cache entries created by cache-store/lookup and cache-store/lookup-value policies.

Alternative approach is to create an API in APIM without any backend and use cache-remove-value to clear cache, and call this API whenever you need. But this only allows you to remove entries added with cache-store-value.