# Remove all cache from Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management

I am looking for a way to programmatically expire/delete the internal cache from Azure APIM. I understand when using custom cache policies you can remove a cache entry based on the key. However I don't need this, I am simply using the following simple cache entries to cache the entire response.

```
<cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" downstream-caching-type="none" />

<cache-store duration="86400" />
```

I don't see there is anyway to remove this cache without updating the policy to invoke the operation to get a new cache entry.

Comment: References: [Availability of SDK in C# for removing cache with Azure API Management]( [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066823/availability-of-sdk-in-c-sharp-for-removing-cache-with-azure-api-management?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066823/availability-of-sdk-in-c-sharp-for-removing-cache-with-azure-api-management?rq=1) ) and [Remove value from cache]([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#RemoveCacheByKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-caching-policies#RemoveCacheByKey) )

Comment: Yes those both are used if you are using custom caching with a generated key. However when using the standard <cache-lookup> and <cache store> which just cache your entire response, there doesnt seem to be anyway to expire/renew the cache for that operation.