# Import APIs to Azure API Management (APIM) progrmatically using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-api-management, azure-sdk-.net

I want to import APIs from swagger/open api specification to Azure Api Management (APIM) using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement`

it so easy to do it with powershel:

```bsh
Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext  -SpecificationFormat "Swagger" -SpecificationPath $swaggerOutputFilePath -Path $apiPath -ApiType "Http" -Protocol "Https"
```

I have a technical need to do it pragmatically with `C#` using Azure SDK through `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApiManagement`

I started from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108663/microsoft-azure-management-apimanagement-implementation/52219492#52219492):

- implement `ServiceClientCredentials` to retrieve valid token and add it to headers authorization

```cs
public class AzureApiManagementServiceCredentials : ServiceClientCredentials
{
    private string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    public override void InitializeServiceClient<T>(ServiceClient<T> client)
    {
         var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}");
         var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xxxx-xxx", clientSecret: "{clientSecret}");
         var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

         if (result == null)
         {
             throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
         }
         AuthenticationToken = result.AccessToken;
   }

   //  override ProcessHttpRequestAsync to use the authentication token as an Authorization header:
   public override async Task ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
       if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");

       if (AuthenticationToken == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Token Provider Cannot Be Null");

       request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticationToken);
       request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

       await base.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(request, cancellationToken);
   }
}
```

From the other side, I have an `AzureApiManagementService` class to handle APIs and products:

```cs
public async Task<ApiContract> CreateApi(ApimCreateApi apimCreateApi )
{
     var serviceCredentials = new AzureApiManagementServiceCredentials(); 
     ApiManagementClient myClient = new ApiManagementClient(serviceCredentials);

    //here where I stuck 
    //I can use  myClient.Api.CreateOrUpdateAsync(...)
    //but it's going to create just an empty API on APIM
    myClient.
    ...
}
```

I'm able just to create an API entity, I can not find the right methods to create/import an API from an openApi specification /swagger.

So I'm posting this this to get more ideas and challenge me in this topic!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From APIM perspective import is the same gesture as create new API (same PUT call underneath), so I'd expect this to be exposed on ApimCreateContract, look for format/value properties similar to how REST API is built: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apis/createorupdate

Comment: my use case depends on open api specification json data, that's my input. How can I create new API using the SDK from my input? The hardest step how to add the same operations